# Can I apply a matrix multiplication between a sparse matrix and a dense(regular) matrix using GNU GSL BLAS in C?

Tags: c, sparse-matrix, gsl

Hi I've been working with the GNU GSL library because I saw it supports sparse matrices, after implementing a bunch of code I came to the moment of truth.
I need to multiply a sparse matrix with a dense matrix but I can't find support for this in the documentation?!?
can it be it is not supported?
(turning the sparse matrix to dense is not an option memory-wise)
thanks!